# While sending the text in the picture to the textbox with the help of the ocr, the text appears the same as in the picture

Tags: c#, tesseract

While sending the text in the picture to the textbox with the help of the ocr, the text appears the same as in the picture

this orijinal picture
[image]

[image]

this is the printout of the text in the picture in richtextbox

so how can i collect these words in one line

Comment: Examine the string. Are there line-end characters or sequences (for example "\n" (often rendered as "\\n") or "\r\n" (also possibly rendered with double backslashes)). If they are there, remove them, possibly replacing them with a space

Comment: Actually, I tried it at first but it didn't work as I wanted, I even had all the words added to the listbox with the help of individual code and then I tried to add it to the textbox from there, but oddly it gave the same result.

Comment: Please past the output of tesseract without ommitting special symbols (like \t \n \r). Obviously there are some \n (= new line) symbols in your output, because otherwise there wouldn't be any newline at all, and the issue is that you're not removing them correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I remembered that I wrote this question now, about 1 week ago, I solved it. thansk for every answer

```
  var ocr = new TesseractEngine("./tessdata", "eng");
                        var sonuc = ocr.Process(img);
                        richTextBox1.Text = sonuc.GetText();
                        string[] c = richTextBox1.Text.Split('\n');
                        richTextBox1.Clear();
                        for (int i = 0; i < c.Length; i++)
                        {
                            richTextBox1.Text += c[i] + " ";
                        }
```

Comment: That would boil down to just: `richTextBox1.Text = ocr.Process(img).GetText().Replace('\n', ' ');`